# Using regexp with sql to find words that match specific characteristics

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I want to write a select statement that gets all the columns where one of them match a certain regular expression.

I basically have this file_name column and I want to select all files that start with a certain word, have a certain word in the middle, and end with 'xlsx'.

I know for checking if if starts with a certain word, I can do

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE file_name REGEXP '^company';
```

to find files that start with the word company, just using that as a place holder.

after this point it can have whatever other characters but at some point in the middle, i am looking for another word, lets say 'dog' and then ends with xlsx.

I know for finding file names that end with xlsx i can do:

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE file_name REGEXP 'xlsx[[:>:]]';
```

My main confusion is how to combine all these 3 cases into one statement. so that it starts with company then at some point has the word dog then after at some point ends with xlsx.

Comment: I'd simply write `^(company).+(dog).+(xlsx)$`

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all conditions into one select using:

```sh
SELECT * FROM files WHERE file_name REGEXP '^company.*dog.*xslx$';
```

Answer (score 0):

If the "words" are not too complex, `LIKE` will be faster:

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE file_name LIKE 'company%dog%xslx';
```

especially if you have `INDEX(file_name)`.